# Перевод нового раздела в профиле пользователя

Tags: поддержка, локализация

Сегодня в разделе пользователя появился новый раздел с закладками - Saves
Т.к. он только появился - весь интерфейс данного раздела представлен на английском языке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше мы могли добавить некоторые вопросы в избранное и позже следить за ними.
Сейчас туда добавили новый функционал с возможностью группировки данных вопросов в разные списки.

Также переименовали кнопку добавления в избранное на "Save this question"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было бы здорово придумать как назвать новый раздел...
Может `Закладки`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил варианты переводов:

> Saves
> Закладки
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18402

> All saves
> Все закладки
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18043

> For later
>
> - <strike>На будущее</strike>
> - На потом
>
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18155

> Create new list
> Создать новый список
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18210

> My lists
> Мои списки
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18215

> Saved in
>
> - <strike>Сохранено в</strike>
> - Добавлено в
>
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18302

> Enter list name
> Введите название списка
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18352

> New list
> Новый список
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18037

> New list created.
>
> - Создан новый список.
> - <strike>Новый список сохранён.</strike>
> - <strike>Новый список добавлен.</strike>
>
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18400

> Save this question.
>
> - <strike>Добавить в закладки.</strike>
> - <strike>Сохранить в закладки.</strike>
> - Сохранить вопрос.
>
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18018

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.

Answer (score 2):

Да, "Закладки". Это и есть закладки, там лежит то, что положено в закладки кнопкой "Добавить в закладки" под рейтингом вопроса. Поясняющий текст к кнопке тоже надо перевести. Он вдруг стал на английском

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Добавить в закладки" / "Удалить из закладок"