# Отсутствует перевод двух фраз в закладках

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закладки

Если перейти в [закладки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/saves/current), то отсутствуют два перевода:

> [image]

Вопрос не является дубликатом для [Перевод нового раздела в профиле пользователя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12153/), т.к. там решается КАК переводить, а здесь — что перевод НЕ ПОДХВАТИЛСЯ.

Comment: Вопрос о необходимости перевода есть [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12153/176217). А то что переводы не подхватились оформлено дефектом на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384251/339911)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод нового раздела в профиле пользователя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12153/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Comment: А нужен ли вообще это перевод =)?

Comment: @Зонтик почему считаешь, что он может быть не нужен?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ перевод довольно очевиден. Хотя по идее перевод должен быть везде, так что его всё-таки надо бы сделать.

Comment: @Зонтик да можно просто enSO пользоваться, нафиг эти переводы :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ переводы появилось [статус-завершено]

Comment: @Danis предлагаю подобные уведомления делать через тревогу "требуется внимание модератора". Добавил [QA](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12634/176217) по теме.